# I am trying to figure out what exactly this line does. I have an hypothesis of what this does, but does not know for sure what it does

Tags: java

I think I'm just having a brain-fart right now but I do not know what this code is doing. It's creating a new object? Or creating a new array (called arrayObject) that is the length of the array named data? I know this is probably a super simple question but I would like to know please.
`double [] arrayObject = new double[data.length];`

Comment: *creating a new array (called arrayObject) that is the length of the array named data?* Yes, exactly.

Answer (score 1):

It’s creating a new set of double that have length of data.length.